# Why $P( A \cup B) \geq P(B)$?

Tags: probability

The question can be put as a statement to be proved:

$$ \forall A \subset E,\space \forall B \subset E \space (P(A \cup B)\geq P(B) \wedge P(A \cup B)\geq P(A)) $$

Well, $A$ and $B$ are events from the same sample space $(E)$. They are subsets of $E$. So one knows that $A \cup B= \{x: x \in A \vee x \in B\}$ ($x$ is a result of the experience). From this point of view is easy to see that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $A \cup B$.

My doubt is how can I make the transition from the set theory to the axiomatic probability. I know that $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ but the $P(A \cap B)$ can have some different results. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have, in general,

$$A \cup B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$$

where $B \setminus A$ is the difference between the sets;
that is, $B \setminus A = \{ x \mid x \in B \land x \not\in A\}.$

Moreover, $A$ and $B \setminus A$ are disjoint sets. Therefore

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B \setminus A).$$

But no probability measure can be negative, so
$P(B \setminus A) \geq 0.$
It follows that $$P(A \cup B) \geq P(A).$$

Comment: (+1) The only explanation that argues directly from the axioms.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to show is that if $C\subseteq D$, the $P(C)\le P(D)$. Now use the equality you state with $A=C$ and $B=D-C$. Then $P(D)=P(C)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ but $A\cap B=\emptyset $ so the latter is $P(D)=P(C)+P(B)\ge P(C)$ since $P(B)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You may just observe that, since $A \cap B \subset A$, you always have
$$
P(A)-P(A \cap B)\geq0
$$ then
$$
P(A \cup B)=P(B)+P(A)-P(A \cap B)\geq P(B)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap B\subseteq A$ so $P(A \cap B)\leq P(A)$. So $0\leq P(A)-P(A\cap B)$ and thus $P(B)\leq P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply: $$P(A\cup B)=P(A\cup C)=P(A)+P(C)-P(A\cap C)=P(A)+P(C)\geq P(A)$$ where $C:=B-A$, hence $A\cup B=A\cup C$ and $A\cap C=\varnothing$.

Used is that $P(\varnothing)=0$ and $P(C)\geq0$.